# How to capture an URL parameter - Magento

Tags: magento

I have the following requirement: my URLs can be any of the following

- http://localhost.com/index.php/?resid=anyvalue
- http://localhost.com/index.php/storeviewname/?resid=anyvalue, or ......?resid=anyvalue

I want to capture the `resid` value and place it in the backend and save it along the order the customer makes.

I.e., if `?resid=133` is requested and the customer later proceeds to make an order, I want the `resid` to be saved (133) along with the order id (say 100000123).

And later I want the `resid` value to be shown in the sales order grid (in admin).

Can somebody guide me in doing this?

Comment: were you able to get this done? I am able to get the param value but I am stuck with how to store that against the user session. I'm checking the user session by Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() could you guide me in the correct direction Thanks

Comment: hi @itsandy i got it done, can you eloborate the issue that you are facing with.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In the controller do `$this->getRequest()->getParam('resid')` to get the value. Save that in the user's session. To save it in the order, you have to add a field to the Order table then you can add it to the Order object once its created. You'll have to then overwrite the Grid Block used to display orders to add that field to the grid. It'll be a lot of work to do this all.

Answer (score 33):

To get all Parameters

> $this->getRequest()->getParams()

To get any specifically

> $this->getRequest()->getParam(KEY)

### Ex:

> $this->getRequest()->getParam('resid')